# What is the proper way to connect to bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have inherited an application that connects to a ble device.

The app searches through devices that are scanned, and connects to the one that has a name that matches the expected name.

Pretty simple question...is this the standard way of connecting to a type of device?

Should I use something more specific like inspecting the services for the expected service ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to filter the scan results using service uuid present in the advertising data. Name is not a good filter approach since it's supposed to be user friendly, and on many devices a user can put their own name, and potentially the same one as you are using.

Comment: Does it make sense to have a blank service with UUID for the explicit purpose of identifying a device type?

Comment: Not impossible, but I have never heard of such an idea. If you have a custom device then you usually have some custom service. If you only use standard services then you should advertise these standard services, so that any compatible app, supporting that standard service, can identify and connect to it. You could also advertise manufacturer data, to identify the particular manufacturer of the device, which is not bound to any gatt service.

Comment: The only service my app uses from the custom device is the Nordic UART Service, which is not unique to the device, so could not be used for identifying it. It is a custom device designed only to work with a custom app, but it does not have a custom service to identify it.